# Lua Tween Part Info

Tags: if-statement, events, lua, roblox, tween

I am making a tween that uses data given from a Humanoid.Seated event, and I wanted to make the camera go to the end point when sat down, however, move back after they sat up. I have a feeling that the problem is with the part info, however I could be wrong.

This is the code:

The Sender/Event Handler:

```
local camPart = script.Parent
local camEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.CamEvent
local blueSeat = script.Parent.Parent.BlueSeat.Seat --the correct seat person should be in

local bluePlayerName = script.Parent.Parent.Buttons.BlueEnter.PlayerName --the supposed name of person

bluePlayerName:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):Connect(function ()
    if (bluePlayerName ~= "") then
        
        local char = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(bluePlayerName.Value, true)
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(char)
        
        char.Humanoid.Seated:Connect(function (isSeated, seat)
            
            if (seat.Name == blueSeat.Name) then
            
                camEvent:FireClient(player, camPart, isSeated) --go to tween handler
            end
        end)
    end
end)
```

The Receiver/Tween Handler:

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local cam = game.Workspace.Camera
local partData
local tween
local length = 2

local tweenData = TweenInfo.new(
    length,
    Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
    0,
    true,
    0
)

script.Parent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function (camPart, isSeated) --receiver
    
    partData = {
        CFrame = camPart.CFrame
    }
    
    tween = TweenService:Create(cam, tweenData, partData)
    
    if (isSeated == true) then
    
        cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable --remove control
        tween:Play()
        
        wait(length / 2)
        tween:Pause() --stop at end point
        
    elseif (isSeated == false) then

        tween:Play() --go back/finish
        wait(length / 2)
        
        cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom --give control back
    end
end)
```

Comment: Heyo Killerderp7, you've said what you're trying to do, but you haven't said what isn't working. Is it not tweening at all? Is the tween into the seated camera view working, but it's not returning once you're done?

Comment: the event to connect to the tweening script is not being called*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the RemoteEvent isn't firing at all should be an clue that the connection to the Humanoid.Seated event isn't being reached in the server Script. It's unclear from your code sample what would trigger the code in the first place, but it looks like you're just looking for when a player's character loads into the workspace.

I would recommend using the [Player.CharacterAdded](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Player/CharacterAdded) or [Player.CharacterAppearanceLoaded](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Player/CharacterAppearanceLoaded) events as ways of getting access to the player's Character and humanoid. You can still use your UI code as a trigger for whether to tween or not, but it might be easier.

```
-- Server Script
local camPart = script.Parent
local camEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.CamEvent
local thing = script.Parent.Parent
local blueSeat = thing.BlueSeat.Seat --the correct seat person should be in
local bluePlayerName = thing.Buttons.BlueEnter.PlayerName --the supposed name of person

-- listen for when a player sits in a seat
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        character.Humanoid.Seated:Connect(function(isSeated, seat)
            print("Player is seated?", isSeated)
            if not isSeated then
               -- tell the client to zoom out
               camEvent:FireClient(player, camPart, isSeated)
            else

                -- decide whether to tween the camera
                local isApprovedSeat = seat.Name == blueSeat.Name
                local isNameSet = bluePlayerName.Value ~= ""
                local shouldTweenCamera = isApprovedSeat and isNameSet
                if shouldTweenCamera then
                    camEvent:FireClient(player, camPart, isSeated)
                else
                    local message = table.concat({
                        "Camera not tweening because: ",
                        "Player has claimed this seat? " .. tostring(hasClaimedSeat),
                        "This is the approved seat? " .. tostring(isApprovedSeat)
                    }, "\n")
                    warn(messsage)
                end
            end
        end)
    end)
end)
```

Also, it looks like the LocalScript that is listening for this RemoteEvent is located in ReplicatedStorage. Check [the documentation on LocalScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript), they only fire in a handful of locations, and ReplicatedStorage unfortunately isn't one of them. Try moving the LocalScript into StarterCharacterScripts and update the path to the RemoteEvent.

```
local camEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.CamEvent
camEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function (camPart, isSeated) --receiver
```

Comment: I have looked in the code, and I know that the Event is getting passed over (I put a print-statement after the event call and it fired) , I think the issue is in the receiver, but I'm not sure what is going wrong

Comment: Ooooooh, my mistake. I overlooked where the LocalScript was located. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help, however I just figured out that issue before checking my notifications